# Time zones in rails are really confusing me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

I'm pulling hourly data, caching it, then using that data in a javascript scroller.  Anyways.  Here's the main issue.  I'm using:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Ok looks fine and when I do :

```
Entry.first.created_at #datetime -0500
```

Looks fine, except it's not when I use the following scopes

```
  scope :hourly, lambda {|h|
    g = DateTime.current.beginning_of_day + h.hours
    where(created_at: g..g+1.hours)
  }
  scope :hourly_by_date, lambda {|h,date|
    g = DateTime.parse(date + " 00:00:00 Eastern Time (US & Canada)") + h.hours
    where(created_at: g..g+1.hours)
  }
  scope :hours_ago, lambda {|h|
    g = DateTime.current.beginning_of_hour - h.hours
    where(created_at: g..g+1.hours)
  }
```

It's showing stuff that says it was created before/after midnight, when I created the record at 6:06pm (-0700)
It's beyond frustrating and I could use some guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't post angry. It just makes you look like a goose :-)

Comment: Does it work if you change `y.hours.since(x)` instead of `x + y.hours` (wherever you have `x + y.hours`)? AFAIK, `+` doesn't do timezones, `#since` does. I might be wrong...

Comment: The issue isn't that my + hours doesn't work, it does. but when the sql query is generated it's using the wrong date/time compared to the data-base using UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you convert your datetime to utc and compare the value against the database

```
 scope :hourly, lambda {|h|
    g = (DateTime.current.beginning_of_day + h.hours).utc
    where(created_at: g..g+1.hours)
  }
  scope :hourly_by_date, lambda {|h,date|
    g = (DateTime.parse(date + " 00:00:00 Eastern Time (US & Canada)") + h.hours).utc
    where(created_at: g..g+1.hours)
  }
  scope :hours_ago, lambda {|h|
    g = (DateTime.current.beginning_of_hour - h.hours).utc
    where(created_at: g..g+1.hours)
  }
```

Comment: Setting the scope to UTC seems to have helped it's now only 1 hour off due to DST (Rails says my server / site is in MDT when I'm in Arizona and it's in MST).